How much does a Hajj visa/permit cost, and is a Hajj permit the same as a Hajj visa?
I read some potentially conflicting claims:
https://www.cnn.com/2024/06/23/middleeast/egypt-hajj-tourism-companies-revoke-licenses-intl/index.html:

Hajj permits are allocated to countries on a quota system and Saudi Arabia requires each pilgrim to acquire one of the 1.8 million available licenses to legally access Mecca.
But as the cost of one of these licences costs several thousand US dollars, many pilgrims try to access the site illegally and typically don’t travel in organized tour buses with air conditioning or easy access to water and food supplies.

https://visaindex.com/visa/saudi-arabia-visa/hajj-visa/:

Hajj visas are free of charge. However, there will certainly be other costs for accommodation and services during the trip to Saudi Arabia.

How much does a Hajj visa/permit cost, and is a Hajj permit the same as a Hajj visa?

The first link talks about Egyptian licenses and the second link is about Saudi visas. You do realize those are different countries, right?

@littleadv both about Hajj in Saudi Arabia.

Your first link says "Egypt to revoke licenses from Hajj tourism companies over illegal pilgrimages". Presumably then, those dastardly companies are the ones charging 1000s for the trip.

@WeatherVane link also says "licenses to legally access Mecca."

They seem to be selling "licenses" for illegal pilgrimages.

@WeatherVane link says "acquire one of the 1.8 million available licenses to legally access Mecca."

@NateEldredge thanks, could you please add an answer? Reason was idk the official site.

Actually, I'm not sure that's the official site after all.  Will keep looking.

But one thing it did say is that the visa itself is free, but part of the application process includes paying fees for accommodation, transportation, etc.  So in effect, you do have to pay money to get one.  I didn't find the amount stated.

If you are a legal resident of Saudi Arabia, you get a permit to perform hajj, it is done through an app. It is free.
If you are not a resident of Saudi Arabia, you need to get a Hajj visa, which is also is a permit for hajj. It is just terminology. Short-term visa holders are not allowed to perform hajj. Again, it is free.
However, you have to be registered with a Hajj agency to perform Hajj (even for residents), they will provide you with accommodation, food, transportation, and other services. They will charge you for that, and the prices are also controlled to avoid overpricing.
Finally, "Hajj Mabroor", that's what people say to people who are about to perform Hajj.

Thanks, this means that the "Hajj permits are allocated to countries on a quota system"  from the first link (https://www.cnn.com/2024/06/23/middleeast/egypt-hajj-tourism-companies-revoke-licenses-intl/index.html) is incorrect, right?

Wouldn't quotas allocated by Saudi Arabia to other countries be on visas instead of permits?

so Hajj permits are also for people other than legal residents of Saudi Arabia?

Thanks, all clear, and I guess license=permit. I have one more question but I'll make a separate post for it.
